# Класс обёртка Integer

Tags: java

Почему во всех примерах, я вижу вот такое:
`Integer a = new Integer(242);` - хотя этот вариант деприкейтед, в идее прям зачеркивает этот код.
Почему никто не показывает вот такой пример?:

```
Integer a = 242;
```

Чем отличается первый вариант `Integer a = new Integer(242);`
 от второго `Integer a = 242;`?
 Почему пишут `Integer a = new Integer(242);` во всех туториалах?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Главная разница в том, что

```
Integer a = new Integer(242);
```

**всегда** создаёт новый обьект.

А выражение

```
Integer a = 242;
```

равносильно выражению

```
Integer a = Integer.valueOf(242);
```

и создаст новый объект, только если он не входит в диапазон значений от *-128* до *127*. Если же входит, ссылке будет присвоен обьект из кэша класса Integer.

> Почему во всех примерах, я вижу вот такое:
>   Integer a = new Integer(242); - хотя этот вариант деприкейтед

Потому, что этот конструктор был признан устаревшим только в JDK 9, а многие примеры, вероятно, основаны на более ранних версиях JDK.

Comment: Поставил Project language level: 1.4, все равно Integer зачеркивает в конце после слова new

Comment: Project language никак не влияет. Чтобы не зачеркивало, нужно использовать в проекте JDK версии ниже, чем 9, либо отключить инспекцию кода для Deprecated методов в вашей IDE

Comment: То есть если мы пишем Integer a = 132;, то под капотом создастся объект. А если Integer a = 102; допустим, то все равно ссылке будет присвоен объект, но уже из кэша. То есть и так и так по сути объект будет присвоен в переменную?

Comment: да, обьект будет присвоен ссылке в любом случае. А вот из кеша или новосозданный - это зависит как раз от значения int-a.